# How to only update contacts instead adding in sync adapter

Tags: android, android-contacts, contactscontract, android-syncadapter, rawcontactid

I have few numbers stored in my apps database. I wanted to match those numbers in contacts app and update that contact with mimetype. Basically how Whatsapp does. They sync all contacts and their app icon comes in contact.

I have done sync part and if i add new contact then i am able to show my app icon in the contact . But my requirement is to just update the existing contact.

This is what i have tried to update the contact,

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(addCallerIsSyncAdapterParameter(Data.CONTENT_URI, true))
            .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID,id)
            .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, MIMETYPE)
            .withValue(Data.DATA1, "Username")
            .withValue(Data.DATA2, "Ite's Me")
            .build());

        try {
            context.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and `rawContactid` i am fetching from

```
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI, new String[] {Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, Data.DISPLAY_NAME, Data.MIMETYPE, Data.CONTACT_ID }, 
             ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + "= ?", 
                     new String[] {phonenumb}, null);
```

I am not able to add connections into that contact. What am i doing wrong. Can somebody please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please share the code by which you have added connection of your app in contact. I am searching for it for 2 weeks. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using `withValueBackReference` to reference the raw contact id. This will try to get the id of the raw contact using your parameter as an index to a previous operation in the batch, i.e. if id=0, it will refer back to the first operation, and if it was an insert of a new raw contact, use the generated id as the raw contact id for the insert of the contact data. You want to use `withValue` here, since you already have the raw contact id.

Answer (score 0):

insert your person data to new raw_contact, then merge it to existing raw_contact._id in your cotacts list using agregationexception.

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> operations = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
        ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.AggregationExceptions.CONTENT_URI);
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.AggregationExceptions.TYPE, ContactsContract.AggregationExceptions.TYPE_KEEP_TOGETHER);
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.AggregationExceptions.RAW_CONTACT_ID1, raw1);
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.AggregationExceptions.RAW_CONTACT_ID2, raw2);
        ops.add(builder.build());
```